# Python 2 descriptors with list

Tags: python, descriptor

I would like to do some type checking on values that are passed into a list.

So far I have made some descriptors like CharField and IntegerField, which work perfectly.

The list descriptor I can't get to work though.

The base field class:

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, type_, name, default=None, required=False):
        self.type = type_
        self.name = "_" + name
        self.required = required
        self._default = default

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self.name, self.default)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        raise AttributeError("Can't delete attribute")

    @property
    def default(self):
        return self._default

    @default.setter
    def default(self, value):
        self._default = value if value else self.type()
```

My CharField class:

```
class CharField(Field):
    def __init__(self, name, default=None, min_length=0, max_length=0, strip=False):
        super(CharField, self).__init__(unicode, name, default=default)
        self.min_length = min_length
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.strip = strip

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, (unicode, str)):
            raise TypeError("{} must be a string or unicode".format(self.name))
        if self.strip:
            value = value.strip()
        if self.min_length and len(value) < self.min_length:
            raise ValueError("{} must have a minimum length of {}".format(self.name, self.min_length))
        if self.max_length and len(value) > self.max_length:
            raise ValueError("{} must have a maximum length of {}".format(self.name, self.max_length))
        setattr(instance, self.name, value)
```

And then the ListField class:

```
class ListField(Field):
    def __init__(self, name, value_type):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(list, name, default=[])
        self.value_type = value_type

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            raise TypeError("{} must be a list".format(self.name))
        setattr(instance, self.name, value)

    def append(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.value_type):
            raise ValueError("Value is list {} must be of type {}".format(self.name, self.value_type))
```

So in the constructor I pass a name and a value_type, which should make sure that every item in the list should be of a certain type.

How should I be able to do this?

Comment: what's the problem with your current implementation?

Comment: Can you compare the type of an element of the value list by the command `isinstance(element, self.value_type)` ? If yes then you can add: `if not all([isinstance(element, self.value_type) for element in value]): raise TypeError("{} elements type must be {}".format(self.name, self.value_type))`

Comment: @hansaplast The type checking does not work when appending a value to the list

Comment: @JohanVergeer: it *does* work: `a = ListField('a', list)`, then `a.append([1])` works but `a.append(1)` raises an error

Answer (score 0):

Thank to your answers and some more research I got it to work.

```
class ListField(Field):
    def __init__(self, name, value_type):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(list, name, default=[])
        self.value_type = value_type

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            raise TypeError("{} must be a list".format(self.name))
        setattr(instance, self.name, value)

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.default:
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.default)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.default[item]

    def append(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.value_type):
            raise TypeError("Value is list {} must be of type {}".format(self.name, self.value_type))
        self.default.append(value)
```

Unlike the other fields, this one can be overridden without an error being thrown, but for now this will do.